# Are multiple transfers with a single program instruction actually occurring in sequence?

Tags: pda, transaction

This question is related to an earlier question I had about having multiple instructions within a single transaction function.
[Certain transactions seem to be untrackable](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/certain-transactions-seem-to-be-untrackable)

If there are multiple instructions within a single transaction function, are the instructions processed in sequence (the funds passed through each account) or is the entire list of instructions calculated and just transferred to where it should end up while skipping all the inner instructions?

For example if I have a single contract where I have 4 PDAs and I want to chain transfer funds from each one after another:

```
//Transfer 1 - (one to two)
ctx.accounts.pda2.add_lamports(lamports)?;
ctx.accounts.pda1.sub_lamports(lamports)?;  

//Transfer2 - (two to three)
ctx.accounts.pda3.add_lamports(lamports)?;
ctx.accounts.pda2.sub_lamports(lamports)?;  

//Transfer 3 - (three to four)
ctx.accounts.pda4.add_lamports(lamports)?;
ctx.accounts.pda3.sub_lamports(lamports)?;
```

What I expect to happen is that the funds actually pass through each of these accounts and travel down to PDA 4.

Is this the way it will work? Or will the entire list of instructions be processed in a way where it will determine that the funds will travel from PDA 1 to PDA 4 and skip the inner instructions?

I should note that I'm also asking this because on Solscan and SolanaFM, I'm unable to see the inner instructions occurring so I want to know if it's because those sites are unable to see it or if it's not happening at all.

Comment: Explorers generally show inner instructions - can you share an example transaction?
As a suggestion on terminology to make your question clearer, this is multiple transfers within a single program instruction. We're talking about inner instructions within a single instruction of a single transaction, and not different transactions

Comment: Thanks Callum! Updated the question with correct terms.

Comment: Do you have an example transaction where you're not seeing the inner instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but to answer your underlying question:

If you simply add/subtract lamports this will not show as a nested ix, you'll just see a final balance for the net total change. So if 1->2 moves 10 lamports and 2->3 moves 5 you'll see account 2 gained 5 lamports, account 1 lost 10, and whatever the final net that 3 gained or lost is after whatever amount you move to 4.

The more typical approach is to invoke the System Program to Transfer (if this is SOL) or the Associated Token Program to Transfer (if this is any spl token including wrapped SOL) by CPI rather than modifying the lamport balances directly. Then you'll see the nested Transfer tx actually move the funds.